# How to add sub-products to a main product in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I am designing a website for wedding cards with Magento.

Each wedding card which a user buys may come with few additional sub products like a Reply Card, an Additional Insert, etc.

For Example:

There is a wedding card named “A”. Now there is a minimum quantity check that we have put over this product. This product comes with 2 complementary inserts per product.

In addition to these 2 complementary inserts a user can buy additional inserts. The user should select the number of additional inserts from a drop down menu. According to whatever number is selected, additional inserts should be generated.

Now suppose he selected 2, so there would be 2 additional inserts. Each additional insert would have a minimum quantity linked to it. And there would be a fixed cost per additional insert.

I am stuck at this position. How can this be achieved in Magento?

Comment: It would help to know what you have already tried, and if you got any errors, and if so what the error message was.

Comment: @AirThomas : I have tried couple of options but none of them solved my purpose completely : a) Firstly i tried using custom product attributes and add those these products as a check box over there, but in that scenario i cannot specify the quantity of each product. b) I tried bundling the options with the main product using the group product option, but in that also the products are fixed and not dynamic and I am not able to add separate quantity for each product.

Answer (score 0):

This feature can be handled by the "configurable item type".
Make configurable item, select EAV attribute which connect that type selection.

This is way how you present an empty default product visible (with name image price) and after this you can make variables by another simple product with other prices store ammounts etc...

The same way is bundled item (there is no price, and is counted by sum of prices or selected sub-items by customer), magento shows "price starts by ...."

Comment: But through configurable attribute we just get sub-products but we don't get the option to add different quantities for each sub-product.

Comment: If you need push customer to buy 2 or more pieces of associated product you can set minimum amount in cart for this  product, or you can use Bundled items instead of configurable. Basic is the same, but you can setup a minimal amount of associated item in configuration.